# Is it possible to deploy to specific machine with bundle

Tags: juju

I want to make a bundle where I specify which machine to deploy a charm to. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do machine placement with a bundle, note to `to` argument:

```
bundlename:
  services:
    mysql:
      # The only machine id supported is machine 0
      to: 0
    wordpress:
      units: 3
    redis-server:
      units: 3
      to: [lxc:wordpress, wordpress]
    ceph:
      units: 4
      to: [wordpress, wordpress, wordpress, wordpress]
    serenade:
      to: lxc:wordpress=2
```

I do not think it's possible to deploy to a specific machine # other than 0 (because we probably don't know the number until after deployment), so it might be useful to deploy to other service names instead of unit numbers.

Reference:

- http://pythonhosted.org/juju-deployer/config.html#placement

Another option might be to use use [machine constraints](https://jujucharms.com/docs/charms-constraints) to ensure you get a certain class of machine.

Comment: I'm using the manual provider, so I know about the machines and the numbers before the deployment of the charms... I'll see if I can specify other machine numbers with the manual provider.